# Script for DHCP Scope

Tags: dhcp, scripting, windows

I want to add our new dhcp scope for around 2000 IPs, so I want any script for even apps that help me to do that, something that get my IP address from txt file and automatically insert and make my scope,

I heard that there is scripting to do this, Is there any script for doing this?

Comment: I think we're going to need much more information about what you're trying to do, your systems and what data you already have.

Comment: exactly for most of them I didn't get good answer, if it needed I can explain most of them, and I am sorry for my terrible English writing.

Comment: Really need more details on what your trying to do. Adding a single scope with 2000 IPs to a DHCP server is very simple to do manually. Adding 2000 scopes with various IP ranges is worthy of scripting... But I can't image why you would need 2000 scopes.

Comment: yes I want to add 150 scope with their options in DCHP, I want to automatic this adding scope, because I have to add these scope on 300 switches too.

Comment: What kind of dhcp server are you using? Windows, *nix, dedicated hardware (eg managed switch)?

Comment: What are these 300 switches and why do you *think* you need to add scopes to them? Oh and perhaps the reason you haven't had acceptable answers to your previous questions are because you ask them badly.

Comment: the script at http://zeda.nl/t11 might be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Powershell.  You'll want to look at the ".." range operator, and have a look at the [Net-SubnetMath.ps1 functions by Chris Dent](http://www.indented.co.uk/index.php/2010/01/23/powershell-subnet-math/).

Your goal is to have PowerShell output a batch file with the needed netsh.exe commands; here's an example to create 3 host reservations:

```
netsh dhcp server \\DC scope 10.0.0.0 add reservedip 10.1.1.1 1234567890ab hostname1
netsh dhcp server \\DC scope 10.0.0.0 add reservedip 10.1.1.2 1234567890ac hostname2
netsh dhcp server \\DC scope 10.0.0.0 add reservedip 10.1.1.3 1234567890ad hostname3
```

The Net-SubnetMath functions are useful for calculating IP address lists when you need something more than just a +1 increment.  Here's an example where I needed to calculate a list of IPV4 addresses that incremented by 32:

Take your starting IP address,  call the ConvertTo-DecimalIP function, and stuff it in the variable $a :

```
$a = ConvertTo-decimalIP 10.128.42.125
```

Then, loop  adding 32 to the address each time.  Write the output as dotted decimal:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 512; $i+=32) {ConvertTo-DottedDecimalIP ($a + $i)}

10.128.42.125
10.128.42.157
10.128.42.189
...
```

You can use this technique to very rapidly create the framework of DHCP scopes, and to insert whatever options are appropriate for that scope; just loop it as many times as you need.

Comment: Thanks I used this technique, but I couldn't set classless static route with 249 value! what is the Classless static route command?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the classless static route command, but I'm happy the rest helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't particularly clear.  However, if your using Win2k3/Win2k8, you can script DHCP with NETSH.EXE.  If you can clarify exactly what you're trying to do, I can provide an example.

Comment: We have Windows Server 2003 R2, with about 2000 Client, We are using 16-bit subnet mask, and around 120 DHCP Scope. We want to change our scope to new 150 scope and change the IP range address, so we want using script to automatic these 150 DHCP scope and options. Is there any script? please give me an example

Comment: I am looking for something like this http://www.phishthis.com/2010/06/18/how-to-create-dhcp-scopes-with-powershell-2/, but this is a little bit complicated.